# User account link not needed on every review history

Tags: discussion, review, review-history

In the history tab, for every post which I have reviewed, there is a link to my account. Can it have a value other than a link to my account?
If not then is it necessary to show it for every entry?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can it have a value other than a link to my account?

Yes it can have different values when you reach 10K on any site. When you cross 10K reputation, you can see other user's review as well. This is why we show username on every review history.

> [image]

Comment: +1 for freehand circle